# Set dataframe row as second header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the DataFrame df1 and want its indexes to become the second header.

```
data1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
columns1 = ['c0', 'c1', 'c2']
index1 = ['i0', 'i1', 'i2', 'i3']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=columns1, index=index1)

print(df1)
   c0 c1 c2
i0  a  b  c
i1  1  2  3
i2  1  0  0
i3  0  1  0
```

Here is the DataFrame df2 that I want

```
data2 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
columns2 = [['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c0', 'c1', 'c2'],
            ['i0', 'i0', 'i0', 'i1', 'i1', 'i1', 'i2',' i2', 'i2', 'i3', 'i3', 'i3']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=columns2)

print(df2)
  c0 c1 c2 c0 c1 c2 c0  c1 c2 c0 c1 c2
  i0 i0 i0 i1 i1 i1 i2  i2 i2 i3 i3 i3
0  a  b  c  1  2  3  1   0  0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
df1.stack().to_frame().swaplevel(0,1).T
```

Output:

```
  c0 c1 c2 c0 c1 c2 c0 c1 c2 c0 c1 c2
  i0 i0 i0 i1 i1 i1 i2 i2 i2 i3 i3 i3
0  a  b  c  1  2  3  1  0  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: You beat me to it ;)